# Filter specifc dates in ASP.net Core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, filter, asp.net-core-mvc

I currently work on an agenda where I want to return the days from the upcomming week.

The code code in my controller for this view is as follows:

```
public ViewResult List()
{

    return View(repository.Days
        .OrderBy(d => d.date));
}
```

However, this function only orders and returns all the dates and not just next week's days.
I wonder if someone can help me with getting the dates/days of the upcomming week and thus the the sorting operator this requires.

Comment: You would probably need a `.Where(d => d.date >= startOfNextWeekDate)` to filter out older dates

Comment: Thanks, I will try that out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a suitable solution:

```
    public ViewResult List()
    {
        DateTime startOfCurrentWeek = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1 * (int)(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek));
        DateTime startOfNextWeek = startOfCurrentWeek.AddDays(8);
        DateTime endOfNextWeek = startOfCurrentWeek.AddDays(14);

        return View(repository.Days
            .Where(d => d.date >= startOfNextWeek && d.date <= endOfNextWeek));
    }
```

What this code does is:

1. Get this weeks start date (startOfCurrentWeek)
2. Adds 8 days to make it start at a monday, next week(startOfNextWeek)
3. Adds 14 days to the current week's start day, to get the last day of next week (endOfNextWeek)
4. returns all days that are equal or after the start of next week's monday (d => d.date >= startOfNextWeek)
5. return no values after sunday of next week, thus limits the output to the 7 days of next week (d.date <= endOfNextWeek)